# Odoo 8 : Is there a link from stock.picking to purchase.order?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

There is this field in purchase.order :

```
'picking_ids': fields.function(_get_picking_ids, method=True, type='one2many', relation='stock.picking', string='Picking List', help="This is the list of receipts that have been generated for this purchase order.")
```

It seems that it is an one2many field, so it is logic that it has counter part in stock.picking, but no, it hasn't counter part.
The code in _get_picking_ids method looks like :

```
def _get_picking_ids(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names, args, context=None):
    res = {}
    for po_id in ids:
        res[po_id] = []
    query = """
    SELECT picking_id, po.id FROM stock_picking p, stock_move m, purchase_order_line pol, purchase_order po
        WHERE po.id in %s and po.id = pol.order_id and pol.id = m.purchase_line_id and m.picking_id = p.id
        GROUP BY picking_id, po.id

    """
    cr.execute(query, (tuple(ids), ))
    picks = cr.fetchall()
    for pick_id, po_id in picks:
        res[po_id].append(pick_id)
    return res
```

Is someone can explain me why? And how to link purchase.order and stock.picking without adding extra field? (because the database is already in prod since 2k15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field is computed so there is no need of a counter part like in "real" one2many fields. But you can try to reverse the field `picking_ids` from `purchase.order` on `stock.picking`.

```py
def _get_purchase_order_ids(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names, args, context=None):
    res = {}
    for pick_id in ids:
        res[pick_id] = []
    query = """
    SELECT picking_id, po.id FROM stock_picking p, stock_move m, purchase_order_line pol, purchase_order po
        WHERE p.id in %s and p.id = m.picking_id and m.purchase_line_id = pol.id and pol.order_id = po.id
        GROUP BY picking_id, po.id

    """
    cr.execute(query, (tuple(ids), ))
    picks = cr.fetchall()
    for pick_id, po_id in picks:
        res[pick_id].append(po_id)
    return res


'purchase_order_ids': fields.function(
    _get_purchase_order_ids, method=True, type='one2many',
    relation='purchase.order', string='Purchase Order List')
```

This is only a fast example and not tested.

Comment: That I was trying earlier. How about if the counter part is many2one field? I tried your code but it works with no error but I don't get the purchase.order related to the stock.picking. I try the querry in pgAdmin and it works.

Comment: I tried with pgAdmin and the don't find purchase.order for stock.picking. I will try to fix the query tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: Do you show the new field in a form view? And sorry, but i have no Odoo 8 demo system to test with, so there maybe is a mistake in the query.

Comment: I show it in tree view only. I keep diging in my side and will notice you.

Comment: After some tests, I can confirm that the query works well. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can search on Odoo were on the **purchase_stock** module has the linked with "stock.picking" to "purchase.order" field name **purchase_id**

Thanks

Comment: if I understant, I need to install the module purchase_stock to get the link?

Comment: No, You do not have to install the additional app.my previous comment was the hint from your about that field exist itself on Odoo.

Comment: You can't check with the Origin field as it's bad programming.If you have the field like m2o and still you're using origin?

Comment: I use Odoo 8 community edition without any extra apps.

Comment: There is no direct relation in Odoo 8 between `stock.picking` and `purchase.order`. The solution is already in the question. The relation is between `purchase.order.line` and `stock.move`, that means between the "positions" of both models. You can use that, to get the relation, like Odoo itself is already doing in the computed one2many field (see question).

Comment: Hello  @CZoellner, As I have already updated my answer with existing relationships have in odoo between stock.picking and purchase.order

Comment: @DipenShah i didn't find that relation in Odoo 8. Do you have the related Odoo code?

Comment: Yes @CZoellner You can take Latest pull.

Comment: Can you just point me to the official code on github? You can easily mark rows on github.